# Create a list of 2 variables

Tags: python, string, list

If I have variables `x` and `y`, such that:

- `x` is always a string
- `y` can either be a string or a list of strings

How can I create a list `z == [x, <all elements of y>]`?

For instance:

```
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
# create z
assert z == ['x', 'y']
```

```
x = 'x'
y = ['y', 'y2']
# create z
assert z == ['x', 'y', 'y2']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
z = [x] + (y if isinstance(y, list) else [y])
```

Generally I'd avoid having a `y` that could be either a string or a list, though: it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
z = [x]
if isinstance(y, list):
    z.extend(y)
else:
    z.append(y)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import itertools
z = itertools.chain(x, y)
```

Comment: This won't work as requested if `x` or `y` is a string: `list(itertools.chain("hello", "world"))` becomes `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']`

Comment: @DavidRobinson This will fail if either `x` or `y` are strings, even if the other isn't.

Comment: @FastTurtle: I meant to say `or` rather than `and`, since corrected. (Now, there is the exception if `x` is only one character long and `y` is either a list or a one-character long string, in which case this would work)